# EWhat could be the more technical term for code written in one place or one file?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

I have come across the term *local concession* that one person used in the Clojure community to describe the code written in one place. Like step by step in the form of a procedure. His argument was the it increases the code readability as changes that belong to one place remain in the same place. I wonder what would be the more technical term to describe this?

Example

Conference topic: agility

`When it comes to agility, local concession is a desirable trait and that is why functional programming is gaining popularity.`

I believe his argument was about the fact that in functional programming we are much more free about defining the encapsulation, cohesion and coupling boundaries.

Comment: Whatever the term might be, it's a very poor programming practice. (Assuming I'm interpreting the description correctly.) Ideally, you want to write once and reuse often. In other words, if I have 50 different programs, and I want to modify a function that they have in common, I want to modify it only once rather than having to do so fifty times. Code should be modular rather than monolithic.

Comment: @JasonBassford If the code “belong[s] in one place”, it’s good practice to keep it together. The problem is sticking code together that really should go into separate spaces. The OP seems to be asking about the former - about encapsulation or perhaps cohesion.

Comment: @JasonBassford agreed in broader perspective, but sometime you want to keep side effects that affect each other in the same module. I guess, I am maneuvered by that conference speaker as clojure community usual way of communication is like that.

Comment: @Lawrence could not agree more. I think, what I want to say could be described by the combination of encapsulation, high cohesion and low coupling concept. But problem is as module grows, sometime side effects are buried so deep in the module that reading code becomes a terrible experience of moving between many files to read one concept (and sometime it might be late because of work commitment), even though modular boundaries are maintained. And this is especially bad for new coder in a team where test coverage and documentation does not have enough priority.

Comment: Since EL&U is about the English language rather than programming, word requests need to relate to contexts that come up naturally in English, such as sentences and paragraphs. It would help for you to [edit] your question to add a sample sentence or short paragraph to show how the requested word would naturally be used. Use “xxx” or “___” etc to indicate where the word should go.

Comment: What’s wrong with the obvious option? Eg “**one file** C/C++ libraries” https://github.com/RandyGaul/cute_headers

Comment: @Lawrence I have included an example. it would be great if there would be a terminology about that otherwise describing this thing takes a lot of time and local concession does not seem to be technical enough.

Comment: @RehanUmar I'm afraid that if you want a reasonable answer, you're going to need to spend the time describing this phenomenon here. I can't tell from your description what you're actually referring to. Is it a sort of "denormalisation" of code, where the same code is included in more than one place instead of being in a separate procedure which is called in each place? I might see that "local concession" is a concession against proceduralisation. I suspect that this question is best asked of the Clojure community rather than a generalist English-language community.